# Web Scraper not pulling text

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to make a web scraper that grabs data from the Milwaukee tools website. And I can make a request and download the website but I can't seem to get the text title.
All I get is
`<div class="result-title" v-html="result.Title"></div>` witch is not the data I need. What I it to return is `<div class="result-title">M18 FUEL™ HAMMERVAC™ 1-1/8” Dedicated Dust Extractor</div>` witch is the first entry on the website.
This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://www.milwaukeetool.com/Products/Power-Tools/Drilling').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html5lib')
tools = soup.find('div', class_ = 'product-listing__result')
name = tools.find('div', class_ = 'result-title')
print(name)
sku = tools.find('div', class_="result-sku")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to scrap the title? sorry but I don't understand what do you want.

Comment: This site uses Vue, which means that the content is dynamically rendered with js. Probably you will want to use something like Selenium instead?

Comment: @amd Is this better? I just want to pull the text title but I think it might be storing the data in javascript.

Comment: You can also look at the requests being sent and determine which is their API endpoint that fetches all the products. Then you can directly access the structured data that contain the information you need.

Comment: @PIG208 would that be the python lib or their own language the Selenium IDE? Thank you!

Comment: @PIG208 how would I determine their API endpoint? Thank you again

Comment: I was referring to the lib. To find out the endpoint, you can check the Network tab in your dev tools in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want the list of the results (Titles) in no particular order you can do this:

```
import requests
import json

params = {
    'Availability': False,
    'Categories': 'BA16CBC0-793E-407A-AED6-DDBB1359AA10',
    'FacetList': '501a4ad5-8e79-40bf-b125-d1cdc48d49ea|d77896af-2dc6-4e90-8d40-3a7c211bb04e|135e489f-c19c-46cd-834f-93092fe8da25|a438883b-2015-4f97-91c8-9a1f1fc5de40',
    'Fuel': False,
    'Language': 'en',
    'NumberFacetValues': 8,
    'OneKey': False
}

page = requests.post('https://www.milwaukeetool.com/api/sitecore/products/GetProductsByProductListingQuery', params=params )
data = json.loads(page.content)

for item in data['Results']:
    print(item['Title'])

    # If you want to print/check the whole item and its properties, uncomment this
    # print(item)

    # if you want the URL of the product
    #link/url
    print("https://www.milwaukeetool.com/Products/" + item['PrimaryCategory'].replace(" ", "-") + "/" + item['SecondaryCategory'].replace(" ", "-") + "/" + item['Sku'])
```

Comment: Thank you! Would this work for other websites?

Comment: @Allan can you explain to me how did you find the API?

Comment: @amd, I found out via Inspect Element on the Networks tab

Comment: @Luca, I guess not. This is for this site alone though.

Comment: @Luca, add a new line if in case you need the URL of the product

Comment: Thanks to @PIG208 for giving that idea of API endpoint

Comment: @amd thanks for your help. I am still struggling to find the API URL on a different website. Any tips to find it? I am currently looking on https://www.tucker.com/itminq09 if that helps. I just can't find any URLS that resemble the milwaukee tools one and I can't even find that url on the web page. Please help. Thanks again!

Comment: Trying to pull all DragonFire Racing products for clarification. Thanks again!

Comment: @Luca I think here you need just scrap data directly

Comment: if you stack in a step it had better do a new question

Answer (score 1):

I think you should scrap the title using the page of the product because when you try to get the HTML of this link`https://www.milwaukeetool.com/Products/Power-Tools/Drilling` there are some tags not loaded so the data you want it will not return to you.

Maybe this way can help you to get the data you want.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  

#add to this list all URLs you want to get the title from

urls = ['https://www.milwaukeetool.com/Products/Power-Tools/Drilling/2915-DE',
'https://www.milwaukeetool.com/Products/Power-Tools/Drilling/2706-20']

for url in urls:
    reqs = requests.get(url)
    # using the BeaitifulSoup module
    soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
    # displaying the title
    title = soup.find('h1', class_ = 'product-info__title')
    print(title.text)
```

**EDIT**

Each URL of products end with `Sku` so You need to take that Sku and
add it at the end of`get_urls` but this way is too slow because you
will need to scrap each page. it can be useful if you need other data
that cannot find in this API.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json


get_urls = 'https://www.milwaukeetool.com/Products/Power-Tools/Drilling/'
params = {
    'Availability': False,
    'Categories': 'BA16CBC0-793E-407A-AED6-DDBB1359AA10',
    'FacetList': '501a4ad5-8e79-40bf-b125-d1cdc48d49ea|d77896af-2dc6-4e90-8d40-3a7c211bb04e|135e489f-c19c-46cd-834f-93092fe8da25|a438883b-2015-4f97-91c8-9a1f1fc5de40',
    'Fuel': False,
    'Language': 'en',
    'NumberFacetValues': 8,
    'OneKey': False
}

page = requests.post('https://www.milwaukeetool.com/api/sitecore/products/GetProductsByProductListingQuery', params=params)
data = json.loads(page.content)


urls = [get_urls + item['Sku'] for item in data['Results']]

for url in urls:
    reqs = requests.get(url)
    # using the BeaitifulSoup module
    soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
    # displaying the title
    title = soup.find('h1', class_ = 'product-info__title')
    print(title.text)
```

Comment: is there a way to automatically grab the URLs needed instead off having to manually input the URLs into the array

Comment: Yes, using the API that @Allan mentioned, I will write an example for you but this way is too slow compared to the answer allan.

Comment: @Luca I rework the answer